# what's the time complexity of this code with sliding window?

Tags: python, arrays, time-complexity, sliding-window

parent for loop has On , while loop has amoritised O n? meaning we consider it O 1? also
min and max operations they will be O k but again On in worst case?
is it O (n^3) ?

```
        left=0
        curr_max=0
        for right in range(len(nums)):
            mx =max(nums[left:right+1])
            mn =min(nums[left:right+1])
            if mx - mn <=limit:
                curr_max = max(right - left + 1,curr_max)
            while  mx - mn > limit:
                left+=1
                if max(nums[left:right+1]) - min(nums[left:right+1]) <=limit:
                    curr_max = max(right - left + 1,curr_max)
                    break
        # print(curr_max)
        return curr_max
```

I am evaluating time complexity for this

Comment: O(0), since that's not valid Python and thus doesn't run at all.

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: Is this a function f(nums, limit) -> int, to determine the maximum width of a sliding window such that no two elements in the window have a difference greater than "limit"? And I guess nums contains positive numbers?

Comment: Yup, but I am just looking for complexity analysis that's all

Answer (score -1):

The worst-case time complexity seems to exceed `O(n^2)` due to the nested loop structure and the repeated `min()`/`max()` calls. It might approach `O(n^3)` in scenarios where the `while` loop frequently resets `left` and the max/min is computed over large slices.